# str_replace doesn't work with array arguments on PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, str-replace, lowercase, upcase

The following code doesn't work on PHP. The actual result: 'ЯЯЯ' -> 'ЯЯЯ' (should be 'яяя') Why?

```
function strtolower_rus($string) { 
    $upper = array('А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я',' ');
     $lower = array('а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я',' ');
    return strtolower(str_replace($upper, $lower, $string));
}
```

**UPDATED:**

I use UTF encoding on the source file. But can't use CP-1251 encoding because apache doesn't accept it. What's a solution?

**UPDATED:**

Also I have checked the following code:

```
$lower = array('Я' => 'я');

function strtolower_rus($string) { 
    return strtolower(strtr($string, $lower));
}
```

It returns an ugly char instead 'я':(

Comment: Seems to be working: http://codepad.org/KWWWPxE3

Comment: It doesn't work when code is written on UTF encoding. And all other string constants on this source code work fine. Very strange issue:(

Comment: Can you double check the `Content-Type` & charset of the page ?

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code below. It works fine.

header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
function strtolower_rus($string) {
    $upper = array('А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я',' ');
    $lower = array('а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я',' ');
    return str_replace($upper, $lower, $string);
}

$result = strtolower_rus('БНAKTARAZ BHATTA');

echo $result;

Comment: I've marked it as the solution but it doesn't work on ugly Rusonyx server.